# MYSQL - is there any option to get the right condition? Both are not get the right results

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT cstmr_type FROM add_vehicle
WHERE cstmr_type = 'Visitor' AND cstmr_type = 'Hospital';

SELECT cstmr_type FROM add_vehicle
WHERE cstmr_type = 'Visitor' & 'Hospital';
```

Comment: And which is the right condition? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: You already know the `cstmr_type`; what do you want from Database?

Comment: The WHERE clause will never be true. A column value is not Schrödinger's cat

Answer (score 1):

Try using IN keyword

```
SELECT cstmr_type FROM add_vehicle WHERE cstmr_type IN ('Visitor', 'Hospital')
```

Answer (score 1):

The same row can't have 2 values for the same column I suspect that you mean **OR**

```
SELECT cstmr_type FROM add_vehicle
WHERE cstmr_type = 'Visitor' OR cstmr_type = 'Hospital';
```